# Unmatched outdent in coffeescript code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have made this coffeescript piece of code but I get an error during the compilation

> error: unmatched OUTDENT near 'callback newResults'

```
$('#ticket_message_content').textcomplete([{
  match: /\B:([\-+\w]*)$/,
  search: (term, callback) ->
    results = []
    results2 = []
    results3 = []

    $.each(emojiStrategy, (shortname, data) ->
      if shortname.indexOf(term) > -1
        results.push(shortname)
      else
        if data.aliases isnt null && data.aliases.indexOf(term) > -1
          results2.push(shortname)
        else if data.keywords isnt null && data.keywords.indexOf(term) > -1
          results3.push(shortname)

    if term.length >= 3
      results.sort((a, b) ->
        return (a.length > b.length))
      results2.sort((a, b) ->
        return (a.length > b.length))
      results3.sort()

    newResults = results.concat(results2).concat(results3)
    callback newResults

  template: (shortname) ->
    return '<img class="emojione" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/' + emojiStrategy[shortname].unicode + '.png"> :' + shortname + ':'

  replace: (shortname) ->
    return ':' + shortname + ': '

  index: 1,
  maxCount: 10
}], {
  footer: '<a href="http://www.emoji.codes" target="_blank">Browse All<span class="arrow">»</span></a>'
})
```

I understand the error but I don't see any problem in the syntax/indent.

My first though was there is no comma after the `search` function, but the code is good when I delete all `search` function content.

This is what I'm trying to do in coffeescript

```
$('#ticket_message_content').textcomplete([{
    match: /\B:([\-+\w]*)$/,
    search: function(term, callback){},
    template: function (shortname) {},
    replace: function (shortname) {},
    index: 1,
    maxCount: 10
}]);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible that you are mixing-and-matching tabs and spaces?

Comment: Invisible incorrect space characters...? A tab instead of a space? A zero-width space?

Comment: You have not closed parenthesis in line 8: `$.each(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an opening parenthesis on this line:

```
$.each(emojiStrategy, (shortname, data) ->
```

But there is no matching closing parenthesis. The unmatched outdent error is displayed at the last possible line where you could close it before it causes a syntax error. Either omit the opening parenthesis or close it at the right location.